# get a link from an <a> tag with multiple attributes using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to get a link piece from an html page, but the link looks like this:

```
<a name="345463" id="325435" href="/site/linkpage/">
```

I need the href, but for some reason i cannot get to it. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Why can't you get it? What happens when you try? What ideas do *you* have?

Comment: I have tried using: `page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");` That does not work it does not give me all the link nodes on the page. The only other ideas that i have had have been to get the parent node of that but still to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the link was case-sensitive